# How to label a form instance within a django inline formset?

Tags: django, inline-formset

I have what I think is a common enough situation, but can't seem to get my head around it.  I've used the `django.forms.inlineformset_factory` to create a formset of forms which allow the user to alter aspects of a foreign key object, and these are working fine.

The trouble is that I want to be able to label each of these forms within the formset (note, not fields within each form, but the foreign key model on which each form is based).  For example, if I tweak the example in the docs:

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import inlineformset_factory

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pages = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I create my formset to allow people to change the number of pages in any book by Daffy Duck:

```
BookFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Author, Book, fields=('pages',))
author = Author.objects.get(name='Daffy Duck')
formset = BookFormSet(instance=author)
```

Say Daffy has written five books, these show up as integer entries all labelled "Pages", with no reference to which book each points to.  How can I label the form with the title of the book so that they know which one they're changing?  I've tried passing a dictionary to the `labels` field of the `inlineformset_factory` function, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

First, note that an inline formset is a small wrapper around a model formset, so most of what applies to the latter applies to the former. And a model formset is a way to present a set of forms each one being related to an instance of a model. So you are trying to think about several levels of abstraction all at once.

Next, see the documentation for “[Using a formset in views and templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/formsets/#using-a-formset-in-views-and-templates)” which describes writing your own template to render the formset:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    <table>
        {% for form in formset %}
        {{ form }}
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
</form>
```

So if you want to label each form – remembering that each one is itself a [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/) describing one instance of the model – you have access to that form within the `{% for %}` block:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    <table>
        {% for form in formset %}
        <tr><th>{{ form.instance.foo_field }}</th></tr>
        {{ form }}
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply @bignose!  Sorry to (continue to) be so dense, but how do I assign the whatever_attribute_you_like?  I'm using the default inlineformset_factory without specifying an intermediate form, and just using `{{form.title}}` (to be in keeping with my eg above) in my template doesn't work?